# Why Github repo has no "clone" option?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-checkout

Well, probably so dumb question but I am not sure even how to search for it, I am pretty new to github. What I do is just watching some tutorials and I want to download the code from the link shared with the tutorials which is to [this repo](https://github.com/dailycodebuffer/Spring-MVC-Tutorials/tree/master/spring-rabbitmq-producer). I want to clone only this directory but there is no "git clone" option for that project. It is only possible for me to clone whole project which has many unrelated code. Do I have to clone whole project(maybe the tutor want me to clone them all) or is there a way to or download only that part ?

Comment: Yes, clone the whole project, then use just the bits you wanted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't clone a single directory. You need to clone the entire project.

Answer (score 2):

You can only clone the whole project, and then target which directory you want to use.